# Parsing anchor tags using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, plaintext

When parsing a bunch of html in plain text format, is regex the best way to extract and examine all anchor tags or is there anything built into the .net lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx is you pal here. There is no HTML parser built into the BCL.

If your input it XHTML (or XML conformant), you can use XML and XPath. Loading the document into a [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) and selecting all `a` nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is good. However I find the [HTML agility pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to be a little more forgiving and is what I would use in this situation.